# Why does comparing a member function pointer to NULL generate a warning?

Tags: c++, android-ndk

The following bit of code compiles without warning for Windows, Mac and iOS:

```
class MyClass {
    SomeOtherClass * m_object;
    void (SomeOtherClass::*m_callback)();
public:
    MyClass(SomeOtherClass * _object,void (SomeOtherClass::*_callback)()=NULL) :
        m_object(_object),m_callback(_callback) {}

    void DoStuff() {
        //generates warning: NULL used in arithmetic when compiling with the Android NDK
        if (NULL==m_callback) {
            m_object->DoNormalCallback();
        } else {
            (m_object->*m_callback)();
        }
    }
};
```

Why is that warning generated and what can I do about it?

Comment: It's good style to compare things with `NULL`, not compare `NULL` with things. Switch the order: `if (m_callback == NULL)`

Comment: It's well known trick to write `if (0==x)` so that if you confuse `==` with `=`, you'll break compilation, not just get a warning (or nothing).

Comment: Some guidelines are saying to put the constant to the left side of the comparison to avoid mistakenly assignments. I think its not worth but there are other opinions.

Comment: @Seth changing it to `if (m_callback==NULL)` still generates the warning, I just listed the code how I normally write it.

Comment: I find the `if (0==x)` trick extraordinarily ugly, but it's perfectly valid code, and I don't know of any compilers that warn about it.

Comment: Minor style issue.  If you get a null function pointer in the constructor, set the callback to `&SomeOtherClass::DoNormalCallback` so that you can avoid the branch in `DoStuff()`.  You perform the test only once, and it's much easier to read (e.g. the default value is closer to the optional argument).

Comment: I would say this is a bug in the compiler and you should report it as such.  I mean, you can _assign_ something to `NULL` but you cannot _compare_ it to `NULL`?  That seems like an undesirable property for any type...  But for a built-in scalar type, it's ridiculous.

Comment: @Andre That's not an option for the real class, the value of m_callback is more dynamic than presented here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're allowed to compare `0` (or `NULL`) with member function pointers, especially since they might not be actually pointers (when the function is `virtual`, for instance).

Personally, I'd rewrite the `if` test without the comparison, e.g.:

```
void DoStuff() {
    if (m_callback) {
        (m_object->*m_callback)();
    } else {
        m_object->DoNormalCallback();
    }
}
```

And, for bonus points, perform this test int the constructor.

```
class MyClass {
    SomeOtherClass * m_object;
    void (SomeOtherClass::*m_callback)();
public:
    MyClass(SomeOtherClass * _object,void (SomeOtherClass::*_callback)()=NULL) :
        m_object(_object),m_callback(_callback)
    {
         // Use "DoNormalCallback" unless some other method is requested.
         if (!m_callback) {
             m_callback = &SomeOtherClass::DoNormalCallback;
         }
    }

    void DoStuff() {
        (m_object->*m_callback)();
    }
};
```

Comment: Why perform the test at all?  Just use `&SomeOtherClass::DoNormalCallback` as the default value instead of `NULL`.

Comment: You can convert a null pointer constant to a pointer-to-member type, see #4.11 of the current standard (not sure about C++03 but it should be the same there).

Answer (score 4):

If `NULL` is defined as `((void*)0)`, you may get a warning. Object pointers are not type-compatible with function pointers. Use a plain `0` instead of `NULL`. `0` is a null pointer constant compatible with both function pointer and object pointer types.

**EDIT** Sorry, I was not paying proper attention. There's a *member* function pointer here, not just a function pointer. Comparing one with `((void*)0)` is also against the rules, and many compilers will issue *errors*, not just warnings, on this.

**EDIT 2** To all who commented: I know that a conforming C++ compiler will not define NULL as `((void*)0)`. The problem is that there are non-conforming compilers and broken third-party libraries out there (I've seen both).

Comment: According to [a page on the gcc website](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bk01pt02ch04s03.html) it says `NULL` is defined as `__null`, a keyword of gcc.

Comment: In C++, `NULL` will never be defined to be `((void*)0)`.

Comment: In C++ `NULL` can't be defined as `((void*)0)`. If it was, the code above wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off the warning with `-Wno-conversion-null`.

Answer (score 0):

`if (m_callback)` as suggested by André Caron works, but I've never been a fan of implicit casts to bools and prefer to use an operator that evaluates to bool.  It's a bit verbose, but this works:

```
if (static_cast<void (SomeOtherClass::*)()>(NULL)==m_callback)
    m_object->DoNormalCallback();   
} else {   
    (m_object->*m_callback)();   
}
```

Still not sure why the NDK version of GCC needs the cast.